# button is not being enabled if checkbox is on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable button only if checkbox is on. What I am doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance..

index.html

```
<p><input id="agree" type="checkbox" /> I agree</p>
<input id="continue" value="continue" type="button" disabled="disabled" />
```

custom.js

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    $('#agree').change(function () {
        var state = $(this).attr('value');

        if (state == 'on') {
            $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled')
        } else if (state == '') {
            $('#continue').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify it to the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsxnqjt9/)

```
$('#agree').on('change', function () {
    $('#continue').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```js
$('#agree').on('change', function () {
    $('#continue').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input id="agree" type="checkbox" />I agree</p>
<input id="continue" value="continue" type="button" disabled="disabled" />
```

The reason your code wasn't working was because you were using `.attr()`. Since there is no `value` attribute, you needed to use `.prop()`. This still wouldn't work though because the value will always return `on`. You need to get the `checked` property accessing `this.checked` or `.prop('checked')` - [working example using your original snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/fv3gk4rp/).

```
$('#agree').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
        $('#continue').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#agree').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled')
        } else {
            $('#continue').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if input has checked :

```
 state = $(this).prop( "checked" );
```

this returns boolean value (true if checked or false if unchecked).